# Want to send email from google sheet with pdf attachment when specific cell value is updated in another sheet and save pdf file name as cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I want to app script save the pdf sheet name pdf as cell value on `'Make Quote'!C5` instead of `filename.pdf` and email the quote with pdf attached email address mentioned in `'Make Quote'!C6` cell when `E1` cell is updated value is equal to `Ready`

I try this code

```
function saveAsPDF() {
const folderName = `Quote`;
const fileNamePrefix = `filename`;
DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName)
.next()
.createFile(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
.getBlob()
.getAs(`application/pdf`)
.setName(`${fileNamePrefix} - ${Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), `GMT-8`, `yyyy-MM-dd`)}`));
}
```

This code save file name as filename.pdf but when I run Apps Script

[This is my sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SK8zTM_9-l2ZCVjv9_jZWZ6-sefmacmEViTilW5JqUs/edit?usp=sharing)

Sheet Name is Quotation

Comment: It looks like you are using backticks as single quotes

Comment: can some guide on above post